# Как поместить в базе данных информацию в одну строчку?

Tags: python, sql, база-данных, sqlite

```
case 1:
            cursor.execute(f"""INSERT INTO '{people_id}'('{subpick}') VALUES (1)""")
            cursor.execute(f"""INSERT INTO '{people_id}'(date) VALUES(?)""", (datetime.date.today()))
            db.commit()
            client.send_message(call.message.chat.id,f'Успешно поставлена 1-ца по предмету {subpick}')
        case 2:
            cursor.execute(f"""INSERT INTO '{people_id}'('{subpick}') VALUES (2)""")
            cursor.execute(f"""INSERT INTO '{people_id}'(date) VALUES(?)""", (datetime.date.today(),))
            db.commit()
            client.send_message(call.message.chat.id,f'Успешно поставлена 2-ка по предмету {subpick}')
        case 3:
            и так далее
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
- это фотография как информация добавляется в бд

Нужно чтобы 2 и 2022-10-30 находились в одной строке.

Comment: сверху case 1: должно быть пропустил случайно

Comment: Можно нажать "Править" под вопросом и скорректировать

Comment: я знаю,оно не меняется все равно

Comment: `cursor.execute(f"""INSERT INTO '{people_id}'('{subpick}',date) VALUES (2,?)""",datetime.date.today())`?

Comment: `f"""INSERT INTO '{people_id}'('{subpick}', 'date') VALUES (2, '{datetime.date.today()}')""")`

Comment: @АлексейР datetime.date.today() - все-таки, питоновская функция - в фигурные скобки